# ROS umet dependency libboost-1.46

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I currently have ROS Groovy installed on ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to install another library which needs libboost-1.48-all-dev, however installing ROS has installed the libbost-1.46-all-dev.

Is it possible to upgrade the boost library without getting problems with ROS ?
Because the third party library won't install without libboost 1.48 being on the system

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106246/ros-umet-dependency-libboost-1.46/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to change the version of boost used you will need to build ROS from source. When you do that it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1